# in G++'s cfg output, what is "bb"?

Tags: g++, control-flow-graph

I'm exploring some of the output from g++'s cfg facilities.  I think I understand what "bb" does - it is a label for goto statements, right?  What does bb stand for? Does g++ have any other ways of labeling places to go to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for [basic block](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Basic-Blocks.html).  In GCC, this is either a sequence of [GIMPLE statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) or (in later compiler passes) [RTL expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html).  Basic blocks are elements of the [control flow graph](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Control-Flow.html).